# How can I match overlapping strings with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the string

```
"12345"
```

If I `.match(/\d{3}/g)`, I only get one match, `"123"`. Why don't I get `[ "123", "234", "345" ]`?

Comment: You only get one match because `"123"` was already matched, and the remaining characters, `"45"`, don't match. If you were to use `/\d{2}/g` instead you'd get `['12','34']`. Anyway, there's an answer in SO to get matching strings even if they overlap: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14863268/2563028

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't do this with a regex alone, but you can get pretty close:

```js
var pat = /(?=(\d{3}))\d/g;
var results = [];
var match;

while ( (match = pat.exec( '1234567' ) ) != null ) {
  results.push( match[1] );
}

console.log(results);
```

In other words, you capture all three digits inside the lookahead, then go back and match one character in the normal way just to advance the match position.  It doesn't matter how you consume that character; `.` works just as well `\d`.  And if you're really feeling adventurous, you can use just the lookahead and let JavaScript handle the bump-along.

This code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8236505/20938).

Comment: As the condition of the while loop never changes this source code produces an endless loop... As @Wiktor Stribiżew already mentioned in his answer one would have to change the index of the regex object to be able to change the matching results.

Comment: @Nighty42 Did you run the snippet? There is no infinite loop there.

Answer (score 45):

The `string#match` with a global flag regex returns an array of *matched substrings*. The `/\d{3}/g` regex matches and ***consumes*** (=*reads into the buffer and advances its index to the position right after the currently matched character*) 3 digit sequence. Thus, after "eating up" `123`, the index is located after `3`, and the only substring left for parsing is `45` - no match here.

I think the **technique used at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)** is also worth considering here: use a zero-width assertion (a positive lookahead with a capturing group) to test all positions inside the input string. After each test, the *[`RegExp.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)* (it's a read/write integer property of regular expressions that specifies the index at which to start the next match) is advanced "manually" to avoid infinite loop.

Note it is a technique implemented in .NET (`Regex.Matches`), Python (`re.findall`), PHP (`preg_match_all`), Ruby (`String#scan`) and can be used in Java, too.
Here is a demo using `matchAll`:

```js
var re = /(?=(\d{3}))/g;
console.log( Array.from('12345'.matchAll(re), x => x[1]) );
```

Here is an ES5 compliant demo:

```js
var re = /(?=(\d{3}))/g;
var str = '12345';
var m, res = [];
 
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    res.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Here is a [regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5mX1/1)

Note that the same can be written with a "regular" consuming `\d{3}` pattern and manually set `re.lastIndex` to `m.index+1` value after each successful match:

```js
var re = /\d{3}/g;
var str = '12345';
var m, res = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
    res.push(m[0]);
    re.lastIndex = m.index + 1; // <- Important
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for the note!  Deleted the related comment: "I think there's just a small mistake in the last source code block: Instead of res.push(m[0]); one has to use res.push(m[1]); as the match result is being stored in index 1 instead of index 0 of the array m"

Answer (score 13):

When an expression matches, it usually *consumes* the characters it matched. So, after the expression matched `123`, only `45` is left, which doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the "How", you can manually change the index of the last match (requires a loop):

```
var input = '12345',
    re = /\d{3}/g,
    r = [],
    m;
while (m = re.exec(input)) {
    re.lastIndex -= m[0].length - 1;
    r.push(m[0]);
}
r; // ["123", "234", "345"]
```

Here is a function for convenience:

```
function matchOverlap(input, re) {
    var r = [], m;
    // Prevent infinite loops
    if (!re.global) re = new RegExp(
        re.source, (re+'').split('/').pop() + 'g'
    );
    while (m = re.exec(input)) {
        re.lastIndex -= m[0].length - 1;
        r.push(m[0]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
matchOverlap('12345', /\D{3}/)      // []
matchOverlap('12345', /\d{3}/)      // ["123", "234", "345"]
matchOverlap('12345', /\d{3}/g)     // ["123", "234", "345"]
matchOverlap('1234 5678', /\d{3}/)  // ["123", "234", "567", "678"]
matchOverlap('LOLOL', /lol/)        // []
matchOverlap('LOLOL', /lol/i)       // ["LOL", "LOL"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the solution provided at [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830) by @WiktorStribiżew, you can also implement the [`[Symbol.matchAll]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/matchAll) method on your class of choice (which may or may not be a subclass of `RegExp`):

```js
class OverlappingRegExp extends RegExp {
  *[Symbol.matchAll](string) {
    const wrappedInLookahead = new RegExp(`(?=(${this.source}))`, this.flags);
    const overlappingMatches = string.matchAll(wrappedInLookahead);
    
    for (const match of overlappingMatches) {
      match.shift();         // Remove group 0 (empty)
      match.indices?.shift() // Remove group 0 indices ([0, 0] or similar)
      yield match;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
[...'12345'.matchAll(new RegExp('\\d{3}', 'dg'))]
// [['123', index: 0, indices: [[0, 0]]]]

[...'12345'.matchAll(new RegExp('(?=(\\d{3}))', 'dg'))]
// [
//   ['', '123', index: 0, indices: [[0, 0], [0, 3]]],
//   ['', '234', index: 1, indices: [[1, 1], [1, 4]]],
//   ['', '345', index: 2, indices: [[2, 2], [2, 5]]],
// ]

[...'12345'.matchAll(new OverlappingRegExp('\\d{3}', 'dg'))]
// [
//   ['123', index: 0, indices: [[0, 3]]],
//   ['234', index: 1, indices: [[1, 4]]],
//   ['345', index: 2, indices: [[2, 5]]],
// ]
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

class OverlappingRegExp extends RegExp {
  *[Symbol.matchAll](string) {
    const wrappedInLookahead = new RegExp(`(?=(${this.source}))`, this.flags);
    const overlappingMatches = string.matchAll(wrappedInLookahead);
    
    for (const match of overlappingMatches) {
      match.shift();
      match.indices?.shift()
      yield match;
    }
  }
}

console.log([...'12345'.matchAll(new OverlappingRegExp('\\d{3}', 'dg'))]);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider not using a regex for this. If you want to split into groups of three you can just loop over the string starting at the offset:

```js
let s = "12345"
let m = Array.from(s.slice(2), (_, i) => s.slice(i, i+3))
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in `Dart` if anybody is interested. I'm sure it could be more efficient, but I wrote it for `Advent Of Code`.

Use a [`Record`](https://dart.dev/language/records), which is just a `List<int, String>`, to keep track of the match positions of unique matches as we iterate through the string starting from different positions. Then, sort based on the match position and output a list of the overlapping matches in order.

```dart
List<String> getMatches(String line) {
  List<(int, String)> recordOfMatches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    var matches = regex.allMatches(line, i);
    for (final Match match in matches) {
      var matchWithPos = (match.start, match.group(0)!);
      if (!recordOfMatches.contains(matchWithPos)) {
        recordOfMatches.add(matchWithPos);
      }
    }
  }
  recordOfMatches.sort((a, b) => a.$1 > b.$1 ? 1 : 0);
  return recordOfMatches.map((el) => el.$2).toList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `(?=(\w{3}))`

(3 being the number of letters in the sequence)