# Truncate text preserving keywords

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a text retrieved from a search result that contains some words that match the string that's been searched.

I need to truncate the text in a similar way that Google does:
[image]

The keywords are highlighted, most of the text not containing the keywords are truncated and ellipsis are added, if the keywords appear more than once in the whole text that part is still included.
How would you structure a regex in Javascript that does something like this?

Thanks

Comment: So basically that's a *help me find a library* question? If yes it's off-topic on SO.

Comment: see the source of google in developer tools you will know

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Some help with a regex that does this would be good :)

Comment: @raghavendra Could you link something more specific? I wasn't aware that they published source code. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: open developer tools inspect the words they are using manually like <em> for the matched it is coming directly from server. so they are generating them in server itself

Comment: @Giovanni (strange I have to say that...) but simply google for: `javascript jquery highlight words :stackoverflow`, browse all the results, mash up some code - post the best you've tried so far - and than ask a specific question.

Comment: if you want to do with js means you have to read the content. match them and replace it will some tags with class or use some third party libs

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the insight, but I did search that beforehand. I'm not just trying to accomplish text highlighting, but something that truncates the text as well.

Comment: @Giovanni You really should post what you have tried so far...

Comment: @Giovanni I realize that. Do you have any code to share so far? I mean it would be of help for anyone to have at least a "working" example code to improve/fix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Javascript Truncate words like Google]

```js
const regEsc = (str) => str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

const string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy book text of the printing and text book typesetting industry. Dummy Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy Ipsum text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
const queryString = "lorem";

const rgxp = new RegExp("(\\S*.{0,10})?("+ regEsc(queryString) +")(.{0,10}\\S*)?", "ig");
const results = [];

string.replace(rgxp, function(m, $1, $2, $3){
  results.push(`${$1?"…"+$1:""}<b>${$2}</b>${$3?$3+"…":""}`);
});

document.body.innerHTML =  string.replace(rgxp, "<span>$1<b>$2</b>$3</span>") ;
```

```css
span{background:yellow;}
b{color:red}
```

#### The RegExp:

Let's say we have a long string and want to match all ***book*** or ***Book*** word appearances,
this regex would do it:

```
/book/ig
```

<sup>(`ig` are (case)Insensitive and Global flags)</sup>

but we need not only to get ***book*** but also some truncated portions of text before and after that match. Let's say 10 characters before and 10 characters after:

```
/.{0,10}book.{0,10}/ig
```

<sup>`.` means *any character except linebreak*, and `{minN, maxN}` is the *quantifier* of how many of such characters we want to match.</sup>

To be able to differentiate the *prefixed* chunk, the *match* and the *suffixed* chunk so we can use them separately (i.e: for wrapping in `<b>` bold tags etc.), let's use *Capturing Group* `()`

```
/(.{0,10})(book)(.{0,10})/ig
```

The above will match both `Book` and `book` in

> *"**Book** an apartment and read a **book** of nice little fluffy animals"*

in order to know when to add Ellipsis we need to make those chunks "optional" let's apply *Lazy Quantifier*s `?`

```
/(.{0,10})?(book)(.{0,10})?/ig
```

<sup>now a capturing group might result empty. Used with a Conditional Operator `?:` as boolean you can assert ellipsis like: `($1 ? "…"+$1 : "")`</sup>

now what we captured would look like:

> **Book** an apartm
> nd read a **book** of nice l

<sup>(I've bolded the queryString just for visuals)</sup>

To fix that ugly-cutted words, let's prepend (append) any number `*` of non whitespace characters `\S`

```
/(\S*.{0,10})?(book)(.{0,10}\S*)?/ig
```

The result is now:

> **Book** an apartment
> and read a **book** of nice little

(See above's regex details at ***[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hI5aS9/2)***)

let's now convert the *Regex* notation to **RegExp String** (escaping the backshash characters and putting our `ig` flags in the second argument).

```
new RegExp("(\\S*.{0,10})?(book)(.{0,10}\\S*)?", "ig");
```

Thanks of the use of `new RegExp` method we can now pass variables into:

```
var queryString = "book";
var rgxp = new RegExp("(\\S*.{0,10})?("+ queryString +")(.{0,10}\\S*)?", "ig");
```

Finally to retrieve and use our three captured Groups we can access them inside the `.replace()` [String parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) using `"$1"`, `"$2"` and `"$3"` (See demos).
or also for more freedom we can use instead of String Parameter a callback function passing the needed arguments `.replace(rgxp, function(match, $1, $2, $3){`

**Note:**

This code will not return **overlapping matches**. Let's say we search in the above string for `"an"`. it'll not return two matches for "an" & "and" but only for the **first** `"an"` since the other one is too close the the first one, and the regex already consumed the later characters due to the *up-to-Max* `10` in `.{0,10}`. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex).

If the source string has HTML tags in it, make sure (for ease sake) to search only trough the text content only (not the HTML string) - otherwise a more complicated approach would be necessary.

**Useful resources:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html