# How to Search a word from a sentence in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code here:

```
<p id = "str">How much wood could a wood chip chop</p>
<br>
<input type = "text" value = "" id = "txt1"/>
<button onclick = "myFunction()"> Search </button>

<p id="demo">Display the result here.</p>
```

and a javascript code here:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var myString = document.getElementById("str").innerHTML;
  var myWord = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var myPattern = new RegExp('.'+myWord,'g');

  var myResult = myString.split(" ");

  for(var i=0; i<myResult.length; i++) {
    var result = myResult[i].match(myPattern);
    if(result) break;
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myResult;

}
```

Now what I want to do here is that:

1. when the user inputs `woo` it would output `wood` together with the number of results found like - `2 results found`.
2. when the user inputs `od` it would also output `wood` together with the number of results found like - `2 results found`.
3. Same with `ch` - which the output should be `chip, chop` - `2 results found`.
4. And with `op` - which the output should be `chop` - `1 result found`.

Comment: Never call functions from `onclick` HTML attribute, use events instead. Please, refer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick

Comment: @ Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Thanks for the advise. Much appreciated. I'll try to update it after that problem is solved.

Comment: @ Ashad Shanto, I tried using it as you can see in the above code but it only worked when you input the last strings of the word and not with the first strings.

Comment: See how it's done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830945/truncate-text-preserving-keywords/31833249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never call functions from `onclick` HTML attribute, use events instead. Please, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick). I have replaced this call with jQuery `click` function - you may use vanilla JS methods if you prefer.

Your code is almost working. You can simply use RegExp `match` method to find count of occurences in a string. You don't need to do this manually.

This code works for me:

```
var myString = document.getElementById("str").innerHTML;
var myWord = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
var myPattern = new RegExp('(\\w*'+myWord+'\\w*)','gi');

var matches = myString.match(myPattern);

if (matches === null)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "No results"; // Any message or empty
    return;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = matches + " - " +  matches.length + " result(s) found.";
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qur67s9d/5/).

Comment: regex should be something like `new RegExp('([a-z0-9]*'+myWord+'[a-z0-9]*)','gi')` to get the full word

Comment: By the way, `ch` returns 3 because it is `chip`, `chop`, `much`.

Comment: @Jorg You can just use `\\w` other than `[a-z0-9]`.

Comment: It can only get the number of results found, not the word referring to that results. As stated in the above question, i also wanted to have an output of the results in the searched string.

Comment: Thanks! It worked now.. but when i search something not in the sentence it doesn't delete the result. Please help me with this one.

Comment: @wwwDELL You can simply check for `matches` being `null`. I have updated it once again.

Comment: This will fail if `myWord` contains special regexp characters. Also, the parentheses in your regxp are not necessary.

Comment: @torazaburo That's just the minimal example answering the OP's question. It will also produce unexpected results if you enter an empty string - if such cases are possible, then you will need to check them.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev you're missing to prevent an empty query. Here's a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/qur67s9d/6/

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to break the sentence into words:

```
var words = myString.split(' ');
```

Now filter the words which contain the text being sought:

```
words = words.filter(function(word) {
  return word.indexOf(myWord) !== -1;
}
```

Then print them out or insert in the DOM or whatever:

```
result = words.join(',') + " - " + words.length + " result(s) found";
document.getElementById("demo".textContent = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a beast:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} sel Selector to match 
 * @param {HTMLElement} par (Optional) Parent element | document
 * @returns {HTMLElement} the matched Element by selector
 */
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);

/**
 * @param {string} str String to RegExp escape 
 * @returns {string} String with special RegExp chars escaped
 */
const regEsc = (str) => str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");

/**
 * @param {string} str String to search in text
 * @param {string} text 
 * @returns {array} Word/s with bold characters (that match str)
 */
const getPortions = (str, text) => {
  const results = [];
  str = str.trim(); // Remove wrapping whitespaces
  if(str.length > 0) {
    const rgxp = new RegExp("(\\S*)?("+ regEsc(str) +")(\\S*)?", "ig");
    text.replace(rgxp, function(match, $1, $2, $3){
      results.push(`${$1||""}<b>${$2}</b>${$3||""}`);
    });
  }
  return results;
};


// The task:

const elString  = el("#string"); 
const elSearch  = el("#search"); 
const elResult  = el("#result"); 

elSearch.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const result = getPortions(elSearch.value, elString.textContent);
  elResult.innerHTML =
    !elSearch.value ?
    `` :
    `<i>Found ${result.length} results:</i><br> ${result.join("<br>")}`; 
});
```

```css
#result b { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="string">How much wood could a wood chip chop</p>
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search&hellip;" autosuggestion=off>
<div id="result"></div>
```

- it returns the results results length,
- bolded portions of characters,
- you don't need a Button to start the search.

Basically it's a remake of this answer: [Truncate text preserving keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830945/truncate-text-preserving-keywords/31833249)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 function myFunction()
 {
     var myString = document.getElementById("str").innerHTML;
     var myWord = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
     var myPattern = new RegExp(myWord,'g');

     var myResult = myString.split(" ");
    var innerHtmml="";
    var count=0;

  for(var i=0; i<myResult.length; i++) {
    var result = myResult[i].match(myPattern);
    if(result) {
        alert(myResult[i]);
        innerHtmml=myResult[i]+","; 
      count++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myResult;

}
```