# Multiple REGEX Matches in Javascript that include the previous match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a results that shows multiple matches.. but this regex only shows one.

```
var regexPattern = /(^.+\/)/g;

var string2Test = 'this/should/have/several';

var myMatches = string2Test.match(regexPattern);

console.log(myMatches);
```

should it not match the three below?

```
this/
this/should/
this/should/have/
```

I have been testing it here. https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/36

Comment: No, it should not.

Comment: It will only match once because of two reasons. The BOS anchor `^` and the greedy quantifier `.*`.

Comment: Change it to `/([^/]*)\//` https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/37

Comment: You could get 3 matches like you state, but you'd have to use 3 separate regex's. What is it you're trying to do exactly ?

Comment: my goal is to identify all the valid folders in a URL.  So a regex that says
[start of string]+[any characters including a slash] + [a forward slash].  I want all three examples above to match.  If you test each of the three matches I list above separately.. they are all a match.
https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/38 
https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/39
https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/40

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match overlapping strings with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex)