# Javascript RegEx: Same character part of two matches

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the same character to be part of two different matches?

e.g.  I would like `"abc".match(/ab|bc/g)` to result in TWO matches -- one for the 'ab', which it will do in this scenario, but then also one for the 'bc'. In other words the 'b' character is part of both substrings I am looking for.

Comment: Not possible with a single regular expression

Comment: Quite possible. Just run `RegExp#exec` and grab the `match[1]` with `(?=(ab|bc))` regex while manually advancing the RegExp index.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *literally* do that with a single `match` call. Once the character is consumed, it's consumed. However, Wiktor points to a duplicate (I should have realized) with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837608/157247) that does a very clever thing with repeated `exec` calls instead.

Another option, depending on the real-life situation, would be to get close enough that you can fix it with post-processing, using a *positive lookahead assertion*. We can say "only match `a` if it's immediately followed by `b` — but don't consume `b`". Then, if we have `a` results, we know they're really `ab` results (wouldn't have matched otherwise) and we can change them accordingly:

```
var result = "abc".match(/a(?=b)|bc/g);
if (result) {
    result = result.map(function(entry) {
        return entry === "a" ? "ab" : entry;
    });
}
```

Or with ES2015+:

```
let result = "abc".match(/a(?=b)|bc/g);
if (result) {
    result = result.map(e => e === "a" ? "ab" : e);
}
```

If the `a` part varies, you may be able to use other checks (such as `entry.length === 1`, or `!entry.endsWith("b")`, etc.) depending on the real data.

Live example (ES5 and earlier version assuming `a`):

```js
var result = "abc".match(/a(?=b)|bc/g);
if (result) {
    result = result.map(function(entry) {
        return entry === "a" ? "ab" : entry;
    });
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I just learned a bit more about positive look aheads ; )

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run two regular expressions. Once a character is "consumed" by a regular expression, it is not available anymore. ie. a character can only be matched once per regex.

Alternatively you can return 3 possible values, and based on return value determine the output. eg. `/abc|ab|bc/g`. This will return `abc` if both are present, then you can simply split on the terminal `b`, otherwise it will return either `ab` or `bc` if either are present.

Comment: True. But we can get *awfully* close. :-)

Comment: Yes, it technically could be matched with a noncapturing group twice, but it would not be captured or returned and therefore useless in his case. :(

Comment: Not really -- see my answer. :-)

Comment: I don't see how non-capturing groups play here.

Comment: You're right. I modified my answer.

Comment: Interesting way of doing it.  What do you mean _you can simply split on the terminal `b`_?  Do you mean `'abc'.split('b')`?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Then append / prepend `b` to both of the generated strings.