# Why does the second part of this regex not match?

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var re = /\d(\d)/g;
var str = '123';
var match;
var results = [];

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  results.push(+match[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Instead of `[2, 3]` as I would expect, it gives only `[2]` I cannot figure this out. Why doesn't the `23` match the regex and give the `3` as the capture group?

Comment: Are you thinking of overlapping matches? I don't think that works with regex

Comment: because it starts again after the match, `var str = '1234';` would return 2, 4

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh........is there a way to do overlapping matches? I suppose I would have to manually restart from the index following the start of the previous match, eh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex

Comment: If you wanted the first part you could do it with lookaheads. Lookbehinds would work if JS supported them, but it doesn't.

Comment: Nothing like editing your question and removing half the content. lol

Comment: I removed baggage that I realized was unrelated to the crux of the question, neither contextualizing it nor deepening it, only distracting. What exactly are you complaining about? I did it as quick as I could, within 1-2 minutes I believe.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I've updated my answer to be related to the updated version

Comment: You can use `'123456'.match(/(?<=\d)\d/g)` on engines that support lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the string `12` is matched in the first run of `exec`, captured parenthesis is `2` which is appended to `results` variable and `lastIndex` property of `re` object is updated to `2`

In the second run of `exec`, `re.lastIndex` is `2` which means begin matching source string at index `2` , So `re` has string `3` which clearly doesn't match the pattern `/\d(\d)/` and exec returns `null`, while loop is exited and `results` array just contains `2`

Answer (score 0):

How to do overlapping matches:

```js
var re = /\d(?=(\d))/g;
var str = '123';
var match;
var results = [];

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  results.push(+match[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```