# Why does the following JavaScript Regular Expression Fail?

Tags: javascript, regex, programming-languages

I was playing with JavaScript regular expression, and the following case really puzzled me.

```
let reg = /(\d{1,3}[.]){3}\d{1,3}/g;
let str = "123.23.2.2.2";
let results = str.match(reg);
console.log(results);
```

I was expecting results to be ['123.23.2.2', '23.2.2.2'], but in reality, the console.log(results) outputs ['123.23.2.2']. 
What did I do wrong? The global search tag /g should give me all the matched results. I am really puzzled right now. 
Somebody help me!

Comment: Regex engines do not backtrack once they have found a successful match

Comment: Because after matching '123.23.2.2', the remaining string is '.2', so it cannot match anymore

Comment: Try let reg = /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g

Comment: Yeah, after some digging, I sort of saw why it didn't work. I found this post very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I was almost driven crazy by this puzzle.