# RegEx for checking multiple matches

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to match all occurrence in string.

#### Example:

```
pc+pc2/pc2+pc2*rr+pd
```

I want to check how many matched of `pc2` value and regular expression is `before and after special character` exists.

```
var str = "pc+pc2/pc2+pc2*rr+pd"; 
var res = str.match(new RegExp("([\\W])pc2([\\W])",'g'));
```

But I got only `+pc2/` and `+pc2*` and `/pc2+` not get in this.

Problem is in first match `/` is removed. So after that, it is starting to check from `pc2+pc2*rr+pd`. That's why `/pc2+` value does not get in the match.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You only want count or matches also ?

Comment: I want matched in array.

Comment: Or, if you mean overlapping matches, `let res = [..."pc+pc2/pc2+pc2*rr+pd".matchAll(/(?=(\Wpc2\W))\W/g)]` and then `Array.from(res, x => x[1])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not a duplicate question. I want `+pc2/`, `+pc2*` and `/pc2+`. Have you got it?

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830/3832970). All you need is to extract overlapping matches. It is a very frequent issue, that is why I preferred to close rather than answer. Answers to duplicate questions are often downvoted, and that is not something anyone wants at SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of recursive regex to achieve what you're trying to get, you can use [**exec**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to manipulate `lastIndex` in case of value in string is `p`

```js
let regex1 = /\Wpc2\W/g;
let str1 = 'pc+pc2/pc2+pc2*rr+pd';
let array1;
let op = []
while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
  op.push(array1[0])
  if(str1[regex1.lastIndex] === 'p'){
    regex1.lastIndex--;
  }
}


console.log(op)
```

Comment: It is working but `if(str1[regex1.lastIndex] === 'p'){` this is static code for `pc2`. Because I only match pc2 not other value.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh you can use regex library which supports recursive regex, you can even make the above function generic, i have added answer as per your specified question

Comment: Yes, @code. But I want the dynamic code to find value.