# Keeping the lookahead value in regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Imagine I have the string `abcdefghi`
If I apply the regular expression

```
m/([a-z])([a-z])/g
```

to it, I get disjoint pairs
`ab`, `cd`, `ef`, `gh`.

What I want is all overlapping pairs `ab`, `bc`, `cd`, `de`, `ef`, `fg`, `gh`, `hi`.

When I use a lookahead, like

```
m/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/g
```

I get the first letter of each pair
`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, but the lookahead per se is not kept.

How can I tell the regex engine that I want the first letter *but also the lookahead*, in order to obtain pairs of letters `ab`, `bc`, `cd`, `de`, `ef`, `fg`, `gh`, `hi`?

Comment: You also capture what's inside the lookahead, like this `([a-z])(?=([a-z]))`

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `()` around lookaheads are non-capturing, and because lookaheads are 0-width matches, you don't get the characters that are "looked at" in the result.

You just need to make the contents of the lookahead capturing by surround it with a capturing group:

```
([a-z])(?=([a-z]))
```

On a side note, there are other ways to get overlapping pairs, such as with a for loop that loops to (the string's length - 2). You might want to consider these options as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by relying on the engines *BUMP ALONG* feature.
By using a zero width assertion containing a single capture group to contain
each pair.

Since the engine did not *CONSUME* any characters it has a built-in
mechanism to avoid an endless loop, which is to increment the *current position*
by 1.

`(?=([a-z]{2}))`

https://regex101.com/r/GYcgiZ/1

Or,

You can do it yourself by matching 2 and consuming 1.

`(?=([a-z]{2})).`

https://regex101.com/r/re917b/1