# String.match returns only first match even with g flag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to solve a ***binary gap*** problem using regex and I'm having some problems getting it to work.

If I try something like this:

```js
Number(101001000).toString().match(/(1[0]+1)/g)
```

It returns only `["101"]`, when I'm expecting `["101", "1001"]`.

Am I doing something wrong or it's not possible to achieve this result with regex only?

Comment: Your matches are overlapping. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex

Answer (score -1):

```js
function binaryGap(binStr) {
  return (
    binStr
    .split("1")
    .reduce((acc,cv,idx,arr)=>{
      if(idx&&idx<arr.length-1)
        acc.push(1+cv+1);
      return acc;
    },[])
  );
}

console.log(binaryGap(Number(101001000).toString()));
console.log(binaryGap("00101001000"));
console.log(binaryGap("001010011000"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do this with regex only, but don't match the terminating 1, as it may need to be part of a next match.

Instead, just require that there is a 1 just after your match without actually grabbing it.

If in the output you still want to *include* that terminating 1, then just map the `match` result accordingly:

```js
console.log(
   (101001000).toString().match(/10+(?=1)/g).map(m => m + "1")
)
```

Some other remarks:

- you don't really need to call `Number`, as 101001000 *is* already a number. The only reason you need to do *something* extra, is resolving the ambiguity of the dot in `.toString`. But parentheses are enough to do just that. You could even just add an extra dot: `101001000..toString()` will also work.
- There is no need in your regex to wrap 0 in square brackets, nor to wrap the whole expression in parentheses.