# Regular expression pattern to match n-word phrases in a sentence

Tags: regex

I want to craft a regex pattern to match any word combination composed of n words

E.g.

I tried to use "(?:\w+\s){2}" to match two-word combinations in the sentence
"one two three four "

I only got two matches: "one two " and "three four ".

I expect to also get another match "two three ".

Why the pattern missed it? Is there a way to fix it? JavaScript or .net flavor is preferred.

After some googling, still not find a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp

Comment: Regex matches do not overlap, once a char is matched the regex engine moves forward looking for a new match.

Answer (score -1):

> why the pattern missed it?

is answer here [How can I match overlapping strings with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex)

> and here is a way to fix it:

```
(?=((\b\w+\b\s){2}))
```

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/mAzYTI/1)

Comment: Thanks you all for the informative link. I solved it. Here is the pattern I used: `(?=(\b\w+\s\w+\b))`. My python and .net code snippet could be viewed [here](https://replit.com/@wood9527/re-match-word-combination#main.py) and [there](https://replit.com/@wood9527/re-match-word-combination-1#main.cs).